# SQL parsing with regex

Tags: sql, perl, parsing

I have an insert query:

```
INSERT INTO EMP (ENAME,DATE,HIRE)
VALUES
('John',TO_DATE('03/14/2005 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YES');
```

I want to parse the TO_DATE portion and replace the date inside with perl. (As '14-MAR-05')

The parsing code is :

```
   +90          if ( $statement =~ /(.*)TO_DATE\((.*)\),(.*)/ )
   +91          {
   +92             my $date_format;
   +93             if( $2 =~ /(.*?)(..\/..\/....)(.*)/ )
   +94             {
   +95                 my ($mon,$day,$year) = split ( /\//, $2 );
   +96                 foreach my $i (%month)
   +97                 {
   +98                     if ( $mon eq $i )
   +99                     {
  +100                          $year =~ s/^..//;
  +101                          $date_format = "'" . "$day" . "-" . "$month{$i}" . "-" . "$year". "'";
  +102                     }
  +103                 }
  +104             }
  +105             $statement =~ s/TO_DATE(.*\)?)/$date_format/;
```

***Line no 105 is substituting the whole end of string. What am I doing wrong here?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the parentheses wrong on line 105, the following should work:

```
  +105             $statement =~ s/TO_DATE\(.*?\)/$date_format/;
```